# Передача файла input type=file вместе с иными данными из js в php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, phpmailer

Нужно передать картинки из формы в купе с другими данными из js в php в котором, на основе пришедших данных будет формироваться и отправляться письмо.
Нашел здесь код для отправки только файла из js в php:

```
var formData = new FormData($(this).closest('form')[0]);
        console.log(formData);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            url: url,
            data: formData,
            success: function(result){
                console.log(result);
                //popup_out();
            }
        });
```

Обычные данные я отправляю так:

```
  $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            dataType: "json",
            data: "name=" + name + "&phone=" + phone + "&" + sbt + "=" + submit + "&email=" + email + "&ques=" + ques + "&formname=" + formname + "&ref=" + ref + "&utm=" + request_url + "&sitename=" + sitename + "&emailsarr=" + emailsarr + oform,
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        }).always(function (){
            thx();
            updateCart();
        });
```

Далее php файл который принимает данные, формирует и отправляет письмо с прикрепленным файлом:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();
        $mail->From = 'test@test.ru';      // от кого //Почта клиента
        $mail->FromName = "Картины LP";   // от кого
        $mail->IsHTML(true);        // выставляем формат письма HTML
        $mail->Subject = $subject;  // тема письма;
        if ($_FILES['file1']) {
            $mail->AddAttachment($_FILES['file1']['tmp_name'], $_FILES['file1']['name']);
        }
        $mail->Body = $message;
        //mail($mail, $subject, $message, $headers) or print "Не могу отправить письмо !!!";
        $mail->AddAddress($mailer); // кому - адрес, Имя
        $mail->Send();
```

Как отправить и данные(взяты не из формы) и файл из JS в php одним ajax-oм, чтобы в php можно было принять это всё и вставить в письмо? Да и впринципе даже если отдельно (двумя ajax -ами отправлять), то у меня всё равно не работает :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот [этот плагин](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/) неплохо справляется с задачей отправки формы и дополнительных данных. Получится что-то вроде:

```
$('.my-form').on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var name = 'Имя',
        email = 'почта';
    $(this).ajaxSubmit({
        url: ajaxUrl,
        data: {
            name: name,
            email: email,
            // .... и т. д.
        },
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Отправляет файлы с  input type form в месте с доп. данными? и как в вашем случае, описать отправку файла в data: ?

Comment: Файлы отправляет из формы сам (из input type=file), в `data` указываете только данные, которых в форме нет

Comment: У меня тут выше по тексту описан код phpmailera , он вставляет только один файл. А как вставить сразу несколько файлов в письмо?

Comment: в PHP слова приходят в таком виде \u0418\u043c\u044f как это преобразовать в нормальный вид ?

Comment: Для других вопросов создавайте отдельную тему. Не за что.